# Can a Persistent Volume be resized?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm running a MySQL deployment on Kubernetes however seems like my allocated space was not enough, initially I added a persistent volume of `50GB` and now I'd like to expand that to `100GB`.

I already saw the a persistent volume claim is immutable after creation, but can I somehow just resize the persistent volume and then recreate my claim?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Yes, as of 1.11, [persistent volumes can be resized](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/12/resizing-persistent-volumes-using-kubernetes/) on certain cloud providers. To increase volume size:

1. Edit the PVC (`kubectl edit pvc $your_pvc`) to specify the new size. The key to edit is `spec.resources.requests.storage`:

[image]

2. Terminate the pod using the volume.

Once the pod using the volume is terminated, the filesystem is expanded and the size of the `PV` is increased. See the above link for details.

Comment: Glad to be the bearer of such news.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the pod termination; it makes sense now, but I didn't see this mention in the blog post announcing the feature on the Kubernetes blog. If you don't delete any pod(s) using the PVC, Kubernetes can't resize the volume!

Comment: Kubernetes v1.11 ships with volume expansion support for the following in-tree volume plugins: AWS-EBS, GCE-PD, Azure Disk, Azure File, Glusterfs, Cinder, Portworx, and Ceph RBD. I use Azure AKS / Azure Disk and in my case I was struggling a bit with some issues mentioned in this github issue, https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/68427. It helped solved my problems as well as this answer and the mentioned blog post.

Comment: [Resizing PVCs which are in use](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#resizing-an-in-use-persistentvolumeclaim) is `beta` since Kubernetes version `1.15`.

Comment: For sake of usefulness: Refresh pods managed by workloads: [`kubectl rollout restart` (K8s version `>= 1.15`)](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/13488#issuecomment-481023838) or [`kubectl patch deployment NAME -p \
  "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"date\":\"`date +'%s'`\"}}}}}"`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/27081#issuecomment-238078103)

Comment: This is awesome!!

Answer (score 18):

It is possible in Kubernetes 1.9 (alpha in 1.8) for some volume types: gcePersistentDisk, awsElasticBlockStore, Cinder, glusterfs, rbd

It requires enabling the `PersistentVolumeClaimResize` admission plug-in and storage classes whose `allowVolumeExpansion` field is set to true.

See official docs at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#expanding-persistent-volumes-claims

Answer (score 12):

*Update:* volume expansion is available as a beta feature starting Kubernetes v1.11 for in-tree volume plugins. It is also available as a beta feature for volumes backed by CSI drivers as of Kubernetes v1.16.

If the volume plugin or CSI driver for your volume support volume expansion, you can resize a volume via the Kubernetes API:

1. Ensure volume expansion is enabled for the StorageClass (`allowVolumeExpansion: true` is set on the StorageClass) associated with your PVC.
2. Request a change in volume capacity by editing your PVC (`spec.resources.requests`).

For more information, see:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#expanding-persistent-volumes-claims
- https://kubernetes-csi.github.io/docs/volume-expansion.html

---

No, Kubernetes does not support automatic volume resizing yet.

Disk resizing is an entirely manual process at the moment.

Assuming that you created a Kubernetes PV object with a given capacity and the PV is bound to a PVC, and then attached/mounted to a node for use by a pod. If you increase the volume size, pods would continue to be able to use the disk without issue, however they would not have access to the additional space.

To enable the additional space on the volume, you must manually resize the partitions. You can do that by following the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd). You'd have to delete the pods referencing the volume first, wait for it to detach, than manually attach/mount the volume to some VM instance you have access to, and run through the required steps to resize it.

Opened issue [#35941](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/35941) to track the feature request.

Comment: but the `persistent volume claim` and `persisten volume` already specify the size, should I create those without specifying a size? is that possible? thanks for your kind reply

Comment: A PV/PVC is used for storage discovery. A PVC is created with the minimum requirements you want for storage, it will bind to an available (unbound) PV that meets those minimum requirements. The PV object is a "representation" of real storage. It requires the capacity to be defined. Once a PVC/PV are bound, the capacity in either doesn't really matter, since the PVC is fulfilled. When the PVC is referenced by a pod, the pod only uses the information in the PV object required for mounting that volume (it ignores the capacity values).

Comment: @SaadAli isn't there any way then to limit the storage space availed to an application?

Comment: Not at the moment.

Comment: "Capacity isolation" aka ability to "limit the storage space availed to an application" is being tracked in  https://github.com/kubernetes/features/issues/245 (targeted alpha for 1.7).

Comment: How could I do this with a `StatefulSet`? If I delete the pod, it will just be re-created. Is scaling down to `0` really the only way?

Comment: If your FS supports dynamic resizing, like ext4, there is not need to delete pods - just run resize2fs on the relevant k8s node and pods will see the additional space immediately.

Answer (score 7):

There is [some support](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#expanding-persistent-volumes-claims) for this in 1.8 and above, for some volume types, including `gcePersistentDisk` and `awsBlockStore`, if certain experimental features are enabled on the cluster.

For other volume types, it must be done manually for now. In addition, support for doing this automatically while pods are online (nice!) is coming [in a future version (currently slated for 1.11)](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/35941):

For now, these are the steps I followed to do this manually with an `AzureDisk` volume type (for managed disks) which currently does not support persistent disk resize (but [support is coming for this too](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/56463)):

1. [Ensure](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-pv-reclaim-policy/) PVs have reclaim policy "Retain" set.
2. Delete the stateful set and related pods. Kubernetes should release the PVs, even though the PV and PVC statuses will remain `Bound`. Take special care for stateful sets that are managed by an operator, such as Prometheus -- the operator may need to be disabled temporarily. It may also be possible to use `Scale` to do one pod at a time. This may take a few minutes, be patient.
3. Resize the underlying storage for the PV(s) using the Azure API or portal.
4. Mount the underlying storage on a VM (such as the Kubernetes master) by adding them as a "Disk" in the VM settings. In the VM, use `e2fsck` and `resize2fs` to resize the filesystem on the PV (assuming an ext3/4 FS). Unmount the disks.
5. Save the JSON/YAML configuration of the associated PVC.
6. Delete the associated PVC. The PV should change to status `Released`.
7. Edit the YAML config of the PV, after which the PV status should be `Available`:

   1. specify the new volume size in `spec.capacity.storage`,
   2. remove the `spec.claimref` `uid` and `resourceVersion` fields, and
   3. remove `status.phase`.
8. Edit the saved PVC configuration:

   1. remove the `metadata.resourceVersion` field,
   2. remove the metadata `pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed` and `pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller` annotations, and
   3. change the `spec.resources.requests.storage` field to the updated PV size, and
   4. remove all fields inside `status`.
9. Create a new resource using the edited PVC configuration. The PVC should start in `Pending` state, but both the PV and PVC should transition relatively quickly to `Bound`.
10. Recreate the StatefulSet and/or change the stateful set configuration to restart pods.

Comment: World class walkthrough. Saved the day here. <3

Comment: Yes, agreed, this is the way to do it.

Comment: World class...fantastic. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

In terms of PVC/PV 'resizing', that's still not supported in k8s, though I believe it could potentially arrive in 1.9

It's possible to achieve the same end result by dealing with PVC/PV and (e.g.) GCE PD though..

For example, I had a gitlab deployment, with a PVC and a dynamically provisioned PV via a StorageClass resource. Here are the steps I ran through:

1. Take a snapshot of the PD (provided you care about the data)
2. Ensure the ReclaimPolicy of the PV is "Retain", patch if necessary as detailed here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-pv-reclaim-policy/
3. `kubectl describe pv <name-of-pv>` (useful when creating the PV manifest later)
4. Delete the deployment/pod (probably not essential, but seems cleaner)
5. Delete PVC and PV
6. Ensure PD is recognised as being not in use by anything (e.g. google console, compute/disks page)
7. Resize PD with cloud provider (with GCE, for example, this can actually be done at an earlier stage, even if the disk is in use)
8. Create k8s PersistentVolume manifest (this had previously been done dynamically via the use of the StorageClass resource). In the PersistentVolume yaml spec, I had `"gcePersistentDisk: pdName: <name-of-pd>"` defined, along with other details that I'd grabbed at step 3. **make sure you update the spec.capacity.storage to the new capacity you want the PV to have**   *(although not essential, and has no effect here, you may want to update the storage capacity/value in your PVC manifest, for posterity)*
9. `kubectl apply` (or equivalent) to recreate your deployment/pod, PVC and PV

note: some steps may not be essential, such as deleting some of the existing deployment/pod.. resources, though I personally prefer to remove them, seeing as I know the ReclaimPolicy is Retain, and I have a snapshot.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing you can do is, check for the storage class that you are using, see if `allowVolumeExpansion` is set to `true. If yes then simply update PVC with requested volume and check for status in PVCs.

If this doesn't work for you then try this (for `AWS` users).

- Check for the attached volume id in the PV (under `awsElasticBlockStore` -> `volume).
- Go to Volumes in AWS, and modify volume to whatever is required
- SSH into the node to which is volume is currently attached (to find node name describe pod and check for node key)
- use `lsblk` to list the volume attached
- Run `resize2fs` or `xfs_growfs` based on what type of volume you have.
- exec into the pod run `df -h` and check the volume.

Note: You can only modify a volume once in 6 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Below is how we can expand the volume size of azure disks mounted on statefulset(STS) pod when storage class is used.(AWS EBS and GCP Persistent volumes should be similar).

**Summary:**

1. Delete the statefulset.
2. Update the volume size on the PVC. Wait till the condition message prompts to start up the pods.
3. Apply new statefulset with updated volume size and you should see the volume getting resized when the pod starts up.

**Complete Steps:**

Check if volume resize is enabled in the storage class.

```
kubectl get storageclass
```

[image]

First, delete the statefulset. This is required because

- The volumes should be unmounted and detached from the node before it can be resized.
- The volume size on the STS YAML is immutable (cant be updated).

We will have to create a new STS with higher volume size later on. Don't forget to backup the STS YAML if you don't have it in your repo's.

After deleting the STS, wait for some time so that k8s can detach the volume from the node.

Next, modify the PVC with higher value for volume size.

[image]

At this point, if the volume is still attached, you will see below warning message in the PVC events.

[image]

Either the volume is still mounted to the pod or you just have to wait and give some time to k8s.

Next, run the describe command on the PVC, you should now see a message(in conditions) prompting you to start up the pod.

```
kubectl describe pvc app-master-volume-app-master-0
```

[image]

In the earlier step, we had deleted the statefulset. Now we need to create and apply a new STS with higher volume size. This should match the value earlier modified in the PVC spec.
When the new pod gets created, you will see pod event like shown below which indicates that the volume resize is successful.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Edit the PVC (kubectl edit pvc $your_pvc) to specify the new size. The key to edit is spec.resources.requests.storage:

Even though this  answer worked quite well for one pvc of my statefulset, the others didn't managed to resize. I guess it's because the pods restarted too quick, leaving no time for the resizing process to start due to the backoff. In fact, the pods started fast but took some time to be considered as ready (increasing backoff).

Here's my workaround:

Update the pvc

Backup the sts spec

```
k get sts <sts-name> -o yaml > sts.yaml
```

Then delete the sts with cascade=orphan. Thus, the pods will still run

```
kubectl delete sts --cascade=orphan <sts-name>
```

Then delete one of the pod whose pvc wouldn't resize

```
kubectl delete pod <pod-name>
```

Wait for the pvc to resize

```
kubectl get pvc -w
```

Reapply the sts so the pod comes back

```
kubectl apply -f sts.yaml
```

Wait for the pod to come back

Repeat until all pvc are resized!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be, after version 1.8, have a look at volume  expansion [here](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/12/resizing-persistent-volumes-using-kubernetes/)

> Volume expansion was introduced in v1.8 as an Alpha feature

Answer (score 0):

I have persistent volume with self created StorageClass (allowVolumeExpansion: true).

```
PV spec: accessMode: readWriteOnce
PVC spec: same
```

When I upgrade PV, changes are not reflected in PVC.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30901062)

Answer (score 0):

I have update the volume size using the below commands in eks cluster

allow volume resizing for the default storage class:

```
kubectl patch sc gp2 -p '{"allowVolumeExpansion": true}'
```

resize the volume to 100gb:

```
kubectl patch pvc your-pvc-name -n namespce -p '{"spec":{"resources":{"requests":{"storage":"100Gi"}}}}'
```

track the progress of the resize operation (it will not succeed if there are no nodes available in the cluster):

```
kubectl get events -n namespace
```