# Resize Disks of running Pods in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-volumes

I have a Kafka cluster in Kubernetes.
I have a persistent volume attached to each of my 3 Kafka pods.

I am planning on resizing the attached disk via GCP API's while the Kafka cluster is still running [client are producing and consuming from Kafka when the resize is happening].

After that I will do a rolling restart of the Kafka cluster [3 pod cluster].

Will there be any data loss if I resize the disk of a running cluster ? Can we still read and write from the disk while the resize is happening ?

Thanks a lot for your answers

Comment: Duplicated with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40335179/can-a-persistent-volume-be-resized

Comment: I saw that post. But I am resizing the disk via GCP API first and not modifying the storage property in PVC.

My question is will resizing the disk using GCP API and then restarting the pod, result in any issue contrary to the post where the k8s resource pv is updated with a new size.

Comment: If the pv is responsible for the creation of the GCP disk you should do the change the PV first.(not tested)

Comment: @Zambozo I am directly creating the disk using GCP API and then referencing the disk in k8s Persistent Volume.

Comment: Then you are correct you should be able to change the GCP disk then the PV. (do a backup first, just good practice)