# Max Data Disks attached to a worker node in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-disk

I use AKS to deploy the application services. I have used the VM size of Standard_D4a_v4 with 4vCPU and 16Gi Memory configuration for the worker nodes.

Max data disks specified for the above mentioned configuration is 8. I need to clarify that, if only 8 pvcs of azure disks provisioner can be mounted to the worker node or is that possible to mount more pvcs (>8) with azure file provisioner?

Comment: for my knowledge more than 8 disk will mount by default is 8 disk only after the 8th disk it should be chargeable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But when I try to mount 9th pvc created out of azure disk, I am getting error like, volume mount got exceeded in the node. And hence the pod remains unscheduled until I add a new worker node to the k8s cluster.

Comment: So fix the issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40335179/can-a-persistent-volume-be-resized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

•   Since you are using a VM size of Standard_D4a_v4 with the said configuration of 4 vCPUs and 16GB of memory, the maximum number of data disks that can be created for this size are ‘8’ as for each VM vCPU, two data disks can be attached up to an absolute maximum of 64 disks per virtual machine. Also, I tested the above said in my environment also as below: -
[image: Maximum Data Disks]

Also, after attaching the maximum number of data disks as above, I also tried to connect an Azure file share as a volume in a VM as below and I was able to successfully mount it and access it. Thus, though you cannot add more data disks to a VM according to the said limitations, but you can surely connect file shares successfully and access them as network volumes through azure file provisioner.
[image: Azure file share mounted]

Please find the below links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-use-disks-cli#azure-data-disks

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/dav4-dasv4-series#dav4-series

Comment: Thank you for the response. You have explained in terms of data disks attaching to the VM. Let me explain my doubt more in detail.
Consider I have a kubernetes cluster in Azure with 2 worker nodes of type Standard_D4a_v4. I have few (say, 16) pods each with pvc created out of azure disks. According to the configuration, a worker node will mount upto 8 disks. So, each worker node will mount 8 pvcs. Now if I create the pvc with azurefileshare as provisioner, will that pvc be mounted on either of the nodes or not (as already 8 pvcs got attached to each worker node).

Comment: Yes, it surely will get mounted as a network file share. And since that is a node in AKS cluster makes no difference in its working other than availability and scalability than a VM of same size. The same is demonstrated above in my answer.